# Request is missing required `Host` header error in Scala Play 2.6.7 Akka

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

In production mode, the server failed to start and keeps print the following log. I cannot access the web pages. But the code runs fine in development mode. How to resolve the problem?

```
2017-11-23T10:04:07+08 [INFO] from play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer [main]
        Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
2017-11-23T10:04:08+08 [WARN] from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]
        Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': Request is 
        missing required `Host` header: Cannot establish effective URI of request 
        to `/`, request has a relative URI and is missing a `Host` header;
        consider setting `akka.http.server.default-host-header`

2017-11-23T10:04:08+08 [WARN] from akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]
        Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': Request is 
        missing required `Host` header: Cannot establish effective URI of request 
        to `/`, request has a relative URI and is missing a `Host` header;
        consider setting `akka.http.server.default-host-header`
```

Answer (score 1):

the haproxy server health check did not send the Host header to the server

haproxy httpchk should be modified as this

```
option  httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your HAProxy version the supported syntax might vary. This appears to be working with HAProxy 2.0.x

```
option httpchk GET /health
http-check send hdr Host localhost
```

Make sure to check [the documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4.2-option%20httpchk) for you version.